# sending a welcome message to client's screen in c#

Tags: c#

Here is a simple server code written in c# . I want to give a welcome message to the client as soon as it is connected to the server. The welcome message will be displayed on the client's screen. How will I do that?

partial sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
        tcpListener.Start();  
        while (true)
        {                     
            TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
            string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
            serializer.Serialize(tcpClient.GetStream(), arr1);

              int recv = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length); //getting exception in this line

            string id = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);

            Console.WriteLine(id);

            }               
        }
    }
}
```

what modification is needed to send the welcome message?

Comment: did you check if your NetworkStream variable "ns" has write method?? or ay be you can pass tcpClient.GetStream to StreamWriter class and call write  method

Comment: can you please give me a sample code fragment? @Viru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try something like this...

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream);
writer.Write("Welcome!");
```

In Client side, you can have below code...

```
byte[] bb=new byte[100];
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
tcpClient.Connect("XXXX",1234) // xxxx is your server ip
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream();
sr.Read(bb,0,100);


// to serialize an array and send it to client you can use XmlSerializer

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
    serializer.Serialize(tcpClient.GetStream, someArrayOfStrings);
    tcpClient.Close(); // Add this line otherwise client will keep waiting for server to respond further and will get stuck.

//to deserialize in client side


    byte[] bb=new byte[100];
    TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
    tcpClient.Connect("XXXX",1234) // xxxx is your server ip
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
 var stringArr = (string[])  serializer.Deserialize(tcpClient.GetStream);
```

Comment: what will be the corresponding lines to accept this in the client side? @Viru

Comment: Anyway, I added code to show how you can read data sent by server

Comment: is there any way to send string arrays from the server? for example:
string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" }; @Viru

Comment: you can serialize your data in array and send it to client...Client can read the serialized data and again deserialize back in array

Comment: @ACE I have updated answer with code to Serialze and Deserialize..That should give you fair idea how you can use this to send any kind of object

Comment: getting the following error while compiling the server code @Viru
The type or namespace name 'XmlSerializer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you have to add reference to assembly System.Xml dll and include using System.Xml.Serialization

Comment: I have tested from the client side if the aray has been received  or not by the following line:
foreach (string s in arr1)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(s);
 }
where arr1 is the received array. But nothing is shown on the console. I have used your code for this array: string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" }; Is there anything wrong? @Viru

Comment: Please debug and check if array has value after deserialization? Post your updated code so that I can look into it

Comment: I have edited the post and  added my client code. Please check it if any error occurs @Viru

Comment: @ACE tcpClient.Close() was missing at server side which tells client to wait for data that is why client gets stuck....Just add this line at server end and it should be working....I have updated in answer too

Comment: :) adding that line  tcpClient.Close() works but I am getting an exception in the line I marked in the post. will you please check it once more? Actually i wanted to send an id from client side and display it on the server side. @Viru

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object. @Viru

Comment: that is because in server you have tcpClient.Close().Either you again craete TcpClient connection from client side or have read timeout at client side and move your tcpClient.Close at the very end in server side.....

Comment: will you please add the correct line at proper place to your previous code? @Viru

Comment: I have given you some direction first please try it yourself....If you don't get it working then may be you can post another question with problem you are facing and code you have tried..I am sure me or someone else will definately help you.As original question was answered,It would be kind on your part to accept the answer...

Comment: I have accepted your answer. But will you please tell me after which line will I create TcpClient object from the client side again? i have tried adding it several places but getting the same result @Viru

Comment: Move tcpClient.Close() at the end of Man program in server. I would suggest you to read some articles on socket programming and then give a try and still have issue then post your question with code and problem you are facing...

Comment: In that case, the string array isn't displayed on the client console @Viru